# VBA Workbook.Open with multiple open excel files giving incorrect value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA coding. I'm trying to open workbooks, read and write to them.
I have to open the first workbook to start the code.
This code opens opens other workbooks and writes into them.

This worked fine for testing purposes. However, when I have two workbooks open and start the code, incorrect value is stored.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Workbook_test ()

    WB_path = "C:\Users\az54\Macro_files\"

    Source_File = WB_path & "Test_Source.xlsm"  ' Source file name


    File_Test = Dir(Source_File)

    If (File_Test = "") Then
        MsgBox "Source file not found at " & Source_File & vbCr & vbCr & "Check for Source file and RESTART"
        GoTo FINISH
    Else
        Set Source_WB = Workbooks.Open(Source_File)
        MsgBox "Source Workbook name = " & Source_WB.Name & vbCr & "Source Sheet name = " & setup_tab
        Set Src_Sheet = Source_WB.Worksheets(setup_tab)
    End If

FINISH:

End Sub
```

The variable Source_WB is not getting the workbook name from variable Source_File, instead it is getting loaded with another open workbook. 
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I added the MsgBox line to see why Src_sheet was getting an "out of bound" Runtime error.

Comment: Share the code where you `Set Source_WB = ...`, otherwise it's hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: This can happen if source_wb is alreay open in Excel. Test whether the workbook is already open before opening.

Comment: @BigBen, The code is in the file "Test_Source.xlsm", itself and this file needs to be open to start the code. Then is `Workbooks.Open` usage incorrect?

Comment: @jkpieterse, Thanks for the advice. Yes, `Source_WB` is already open. Checking for open workbook did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Src_Sheet = Source_WB.Worksheets(setup_tab)
```

to

```
Src_Sheet = Source_WB.Sheets("setup_tab")
```

Comment: Thank you, but `setup_tab` is a variable name. Hence this may not suit my requirement.

Comment: What is setup_tab? Your code is incomplete as it doesn't provide any details of what this is...